# Issue if string includes substring

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to check if a substring is in a string.

The string come from the 12th row of a Google sheet.
The substring come from an HTML form where the user inserts data. (It's a simple string in the example below and it still doesn't work. The problem is not the data inserted.)

I want to display the row number of the string when the substring is detected.

```
for (var i=0; i < sheetDataRange.getValues().length; i++) {
  if (sheetDataRange.getValues()[i][11].includes("I14")) { // The string value is okay
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(i+5); // The data starts at the 5th row
  }
}
```

I tried to resolve the issue with the includes() function.
The issue is that some rows without "I14" are displayed and other with it are not.
I tried to use the match() function too but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that sheetDataRange starts from row 5?

Comment: *The string come from the 12th row* but `getValues()[i][11` is 12th **column** not a row. And actually you're using terribly wrong the method `getValues()`. Try @Cooper's solution.

Comment: funkizer, Yes, sure about it. The issue is in the condition.

Yuri, I used the wrong word. The string comes from somewhere in the 12th column. Not row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to getValues() once not everytime you go through the loop

```
const values = sheetDataRange.getValues();
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
for (var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
  if (values[i][11].toString().includes("I14")) { 
    ui.alert(i+5); // The data starts at the 5th row
  }
}
```